# How can I change the URL for a single page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm using wordpress as the CMS. I have developed a custom plugin to show dealers information.

below is the URL.

http://example.nl/dealer-info/dealer-informatie/?n=91&d=dealer-name

`91` is the dealers ID which is used to fetch the data from the DB.

Is it possible for me to change to URL as below.

http://example.nl/dealer-info/dealer-informatie/91/dealer-name

## or

http://example.nl/dealer-info/dealer-informatie/?n=91/dealer-name

My purpose is to just to add `/dealer-name` to the URL.

How can I change the URL for a single page in Wordpress?

Given that I don't want to change the permalinks which will affect the whole site. I'm aware the fact that this can be done using .htaccess but I don't the how to do it. Help me out if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dealer-info/dealer-informatie/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /dealer-info/dealer-informatie/?n=$1&d=$2 [L]
```

You'll want to add that *before* any wordpress specificf rules in your document root.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom post type were 'product', and/or query_var = "product", WordPress would look for single-product.php to display the single or permalink of the post.

Use single-{post_type}.php

For More Information refer to the below link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates