# Custom URL on a single page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, custom-url

I'm trying to figure out how to create a custom URL for only one page on Wordpress.  The answer here might be pointing in the right direction but I'm not really sure how to implement it. [How can I change the URL for a single page in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626910/how-can-i-change-the-url-for-a-single-page-in-wordpress)

In wordpress I was hoping to create a page and let's say for example the default URL of that page is 
             `http://wordpress/?page_id=772`
I want to change that URL to be the following

`http://wordpress/share_this.php?pid=rk_379061`

The URL must be in that format as the url is generated and embedded into an email by 3rd party software.

So I was thinking if there was a way to change `page_id=772` to `share_this.php` and then allow the file some way to consume the parameters pid=rk_379061.

I've had a look at my .htacess file and it just includes the following : 
`# BEGIN WordPress # END WordPress`

I'm not really where else to look.

Any ideas.  and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this (must be above your `# BEGIN WordPress` line)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^share_this\.php$ /?page=772 [L,QSA]
```

This will take the request `/share_this.php?pid=rk_379061` and rewrite it to: `/?page_id=772&pid=rk_379061`, so that the `pid` parameter can be accessed.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an Internal Server Error, but it feels like it's going the right direction...

Comment: Can I ask what the [L, QSA] mean?

Comment: @LindaKeating the `L` flag says to stop rewriting for the current iteration, and `QSA` means to append the query string to the end. Make sure you have mod_rewrite turned on, otherwise check your error logs to see why you're getting a 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Add a `share_this.php` file to your Wordpress root that uses `$_GET['pid']` and do whatever you need to do with it.

Example:

```
// wordpress/share_this.php

<?php

$pid = $_GET['pid'];
if( $pid == "rk_379061" )
{
    header( "Location: /?page_id=772" );
}
else
{
    header( "Location: /" );
}

?>
```